# Get Right of Either in c# Functional Programming?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn functional programming using c#

I am using https://github.com/louthy/language-ext

How can I extract the right value from Either, without using `.Match`?

How can I return the result of `UpdateLocations` without the temporary variable?

### Either

```
public static Either<Exception, string[]> ExtractStringArray(IQueryCollection query, string filter)
        {
            try
            {
                return query.First(x => x.Key.ToLower() == filter).Value.ToString().Split(',').ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex;
            }
        }
```

### Exception Case

```
 static void HandleException(Exception ex) => Console.WriteLine(ex);
```

I'm extracting the output by using the code below, is there another alternative?

```
 private static string[] UpdateLocations(IQueryCollection query)
        {
            // creating a temporary value here
            string[] locations = new string[] { };

            ExtractStringArray(query, "location")
                .Match(
                    Left: ex => HandleException(ex),
                    Right: loc => locations = loc);

            return locations;
        }
```

### Updating a variable

```
   var query = request.Query;
   result.Locations = UpdateLocations(query);
```

Comment: An either with an exception or value T sounds to me like a Try<T>. You would still need to do a match on the function call result. To avoid the temp value you could return from the match lambda. That would mean moving the empty array as a return of Left/Fail and actual location on Right/Succ

Comment: Getting up and running with langext could have been better for me if the documentation had been more detailed or with very specific examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// simplify ExtractStringArray using Try
static Either<Exception, string[]> ExtractStringArray(IQueryCollection query, string filter) =>
    Try(() => query.First(x => x.Key.ToLower() == filter).Value.ToString().Split(',').ToArray())
      .ToEither();

static void HandleException(Exception ex) => Console.WriteLine(ex);

var query = request.Query;
// now get result or exception (Either<...>)
var resultOrException = ExtractStringArray(query, "location");

// now execute side-effect if exception
resultOrException.IfLeft(HandleException); // side-effect (log error)

// now use result and supply default value in case of exception
result.Locations = resultOrException.IfLeft(new string[]{ });
```